How to position TextInputLayout's endIconMode="clear_text" to the left side of the TextInputEditText?
I am using android:gravity="end" on TextInputEditText and the placement of the end icon in this case is far from ideal, as shown in the following image. Note that the both the hint and value realign back to the right edge when the icon changes visibility (on focus change, for example).

It would be perfect to have the end icon where the start icon is placed. As well, in order to avoid re-implementing the whole thing, it would be preferable to find a solution that uses existing clear_text functionality as much as possible.
I expected that start|end icon reversal is supported for right-to-left layouts and that it can be reused somehow, but setting android:layoutDirection="rtl" on TextInputLayout or TextInputEditText doesn't have any effect.
Here is the layout snippet from my example:
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/Base"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    >
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextBase"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:gravity="end"
    />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

Thanks in advance for your feedback.
